# Npm error- when trying to install new dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

Sometimes I get the following error when using Node version 4.4.6:

[image: react-test-renderer not found, react-test-renderer is not in the npm registry]

- react-test-renderer not found, react-test-renderer is not in the npm registry

Installing the latest version of Node didn't fix the issue.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Note: This is a Windows machine for development.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: If you change the package version to 'https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-test-renderer' in your package.json does that install?

Comment: yes, I am using proxy